# Cannot delete Categories, tags! Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add, delete default categories under default word press post. (means not creating any custom taxonomy etc)

**Problem:** Into the admin panel when I click on delete action for the category or a tag, it displays the error message "`An unidentified error has occurred.`" http://prntscr.com/f5eqkh.

Ajax response is showing `You cannot delete terms (categories, tags, etc)You can't delete category A and B. Please deselect those and try again`,but upon refreshing the page the category was no more in the list (means deleted).

**Tried:** I've deleted all the plugins. Reverted the theme back to twentyfifteen.

But still, it does not add or delete the categories and tags without page refresh.

Is it in databases or something else? I am using the latest version of wp 4.7.4.

Comment: Please, go to users, and create a new user with an administrative role, and try to delete them with his account. Then tell me what happens, please to solve the problem easier!

Comment: If happening same, please, send me the code of your .htaccess file on your FTP.

Comment: @Atanas Thanks. I'm logged in with super admin with all rights into the admin panel. and the htaccess file is default generated by word press. Nothing extra stuff added into it by me.

Comment: Ok, but sometimes, wordpress doesn't install with a correct htaccess, so please send me it's code!

Comment: Also try the first way! There are almost always bugs, so try to find them!

Comment: Thank you @Atanas. Yes it is something with administrative role. i've configured it with installing a fresh copy of wordpress again, and come to the solution, the plugin "User Role Editor" might have added a role "administrator" and it is kind of permission issue. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in past.

I have checked everything like you did. And then just find some spaces in my `function.php` file and unwanted `<?php ?>` PHP used in many line.

If you are using only PHP code for multiple lines then make sure do not use PHP tag multiple times in your code and also make sure no any unwanted spaces in the top, middle and bottom of your `function.php` file.

Try to check it once, It might solve your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this method. But no luck. In fact i uploaded fresh twenty sixteen theme from new package and disabled all the plugins. But no luck. :(